# How to extract decimal number from string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp, struts-1

I want to extract decimal number `265.12` or `0.0` from alphanumeric string (say amount) having value `$265.12+` or `$265.12-` or `$0.0+` or `$0.0-` and use it apply struts logic tag in JSP. Not sure how to extract number maybe with help of JavaScript.

Answer (score 33):

You can use regex like this,

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2qdV/)

```
var amount = "$265.12+";
var doublenumber = Number(amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

Answer (score 12):

Without error checks, following will do:

```
var string = "$123123.0980soigfusofui"
var number = parseFloat(string.match(/[\d\.]+/))
```

123123.098

Comment: I believe the regex can be shortened to `/[\d.]+/` - stumbled upon that in JS

Answer (score -1):

Try this also,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    var amount =  $("#amount").val();
    alert(amount.split(".")[1]);
} </script>
</head> 
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="25.50">
<input type="submit" onclick="validate();">
```

Answer (score -1):

A more elegant solution and also a method to avoid the `0.7700000004` javascript math do this:

`var num = 15.3354;
Number(String(num).substr(String(num).indexOf('.')+1));`

The result will always be the exact number of decimals. Also a `prototype` for easier use

`Number.prototype.getDecimals = function () {
    return Number(String(this).substr(String(this).indexOf('.')+1));
}`

so now just `15.6655.getDecimals() ==> 6655`

Answer (score -2):

You might be interested in this library for formatting money http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/

Comment: How could he when he needs to extract, not print?

Comment: there's a method called unformat() that returns number. E.g. accounting.unformat("$ 12,345,678.90"); // 12345678.9

Answer (score -3):

use :

```
var str = parseFloat("$265.12".match(/[\d\.]+/))
alert(str % 1); => 0.12000000000000455
```