# javascript regular expression find decimal values

Tags: javascript

I have requirement to get the decimal values from string if it exists otherwise null, how can do that in javascript, the below are possibilities values i want to get the decimal value.

6Pay-30D
3Pay-30D 19.95-1st Pay Amount
3Pay-30D SH3Pay

Comment: here is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411833/how-to-extract-decimal-number-from-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

this is the regex please have a look

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]*
```

or this is the refined one

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

actually, I don't know if you want all the numbers out, you can try like this:

```
var str = "6Pay-30D 3Pay-30D 19.95-1st Pay Amount 3Pay-30D SH3Pay";
str.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
```

below is the output:

```
['6','30','3','30','19.95','1','3','30','3']
```

if you just want "19.95" in the input. you'll try like this:

```
str.match(/\d+(\.\d+){1}/g);
```

below is the output:

```
[ '19.95' ]
```

finally, if you just want first matched result, just remove the 'g'.
hope it helpful.