# Return only numbers from string

Tags: javascript

I have a value in Javascript as

```
var input = "Rs. 6,67,000"
```

How can I get only the numerical values ?

**Result:** `667000`

**Current Approach (not working)**

```
var input = "Rs. 6,67,000";
var res = str.replace("Rs. ", "").replace(",","");
alert(res);

Result: 667,000
```

Comment: You need to use a regular expression to make it easier.

Comment: change replace() to replaceAll() or use Regexp, as mentioned by others.

Comment: @SzybkiSasza There is no `replaceAll()` in `javascript`.

Comment: @Karan, Yes there is.

Comment: @myjobistobehappy, At the time I have posted a comment there wasn't but now there is a `replaceAll()` in `javascript`. https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-string-replaceall-has-landed-in-all-major-browsers-9417e2f831d4.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411872/3063884 (works with decimals)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

This is a great use for a regular expression.

```js
    var str = "Rs. 6,67,000";
    var res = str.replace(/\D/g, "");
    alert(res); // 667000
```

`\D` matches a character that is *not* a numerical digit. So any non digit is replaced by an empty string. The result is only the digits in a string.

The `g` at the end of the regular expression literal is for "global" meaning that it replaces all matches, and not just the first.

This approach will work for a variety of input formats, so if that `"Rs."` becomes something else later, this code won't break.

Comment: Let's say I want to put all these numbers in an Array, how do I separate the result (i.e. 667000) with commas?

Comment: @ed1nh0 `'123'.split('') //=> ['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: Alex Wayne a colleague gave me this solution `res.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);`

What do you think?

Comment: I had to use `parseInt(res)` or my JS treated the `res` as a string. I feel this should be incorporated into the function personally as the goal is to get a integer~! otherwise, great answer!

Comment: This doesn't handle decimal points. OK for integers.

Answer (score 11):

For this task the easiest way to do it will be to us regex :)

```js
var input = "Rs. 6,67,000";
var res = input.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(res); // 667000
```

Here you can find more information about how to use regex:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I hope it helped :)

Regards

Answer (score 7):

You can make a function like this

```js
function justNumbers(string) {
  var numsStr = string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  return parseInt(numsStr);
}

var input = "Rs. 6,67,000";
var number = justNumbers(input);
console.log(number); // 667000
```

Comment: congrats for the aswner, it'll work whetever the value of the string

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
str.replace('Rs. ', '').replace(/,/g, '');
```

or

```
str.replace(/Rs. |,/g, '');
```

- `/,/g` is a regular expression. `g` means `global`
- `/Rs. |,/g` is a single regular expression that matches every occurence of `Rs.` or `,`

Answer (score 2):

If by chance you **need the comma** you can use the code bellow:

```
var input = "Rs. 6,67,000"
const numbers = str.match(/(\d|,)+/g).pop();

// 6,67,000
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. Change your replace to use the `g` flag, which will replace all.

```
str.replace("Rs. ", "").replace(/,/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "Rs. 6,67,000";

input = input.replace("Rs. ", "");

//loop through string and replace all commas
while (input.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    input = input.replace(",","");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var input = "ds. 7,765,000";
var cleantxt = input.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
var output = cleantxt.replace(/\,/g, "");
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var input = "Rs. 6,67,000";
var res = input.replace(/Rs. |,/g, '');
alert(res); // 667000
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thesupercoder/frw495s4/)