# JavaScript - Best way to extract string of numbers between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need a regular expression to extract a string of digits out of a string
the string can look like this:

> B01234567XXXX

while B is always B and XXXX can be anything: digits, symbols, letters

but the numbers are always 8 digits.

example:

```
B01234567ABCD output: 01234567
B012345678901 output: 01234567
B01234567¿☺♥◘ output: 01234567
B01234567XXXX output: 01234567
B0123456787@X output: 01234567
```

This is a part of a barcode reader function, if the letters are in the formation mentioned so its an ID, else its a barcode, so anyway should be an output, meaning it could be 
B012345670020 as input
but the output should still be 01234567

What I've tried, after looking on google:

```
if (vm.BarcodeInput[0]=='B') {
    let regex = /\d{8}\g;
    let found = vm.BarcodeInput.match(regex);

}
```

I'm looking for a better-looking way to do so,
I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What do you expect the output to be given that string in the question.

Comment: Regular expressions :)

Comment: try this link to find specific out. 
https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607419/return-only-numbers-from-string

Comment: how is that a duplicate?! it's a completely different question

Comment: *"T is a character"* do you mean *letter*? Do you want to get all numbers after B till the next letter?

Comment: So it could be a number as well?

Comment: OK, so how to you know whether "T" is ... "T" or a digit you want to extract? Do you simply want omit the last four characters of the string? *"when i get something like this: 0123456789 "* Can you get that though? Isn't there always a B?

Comment: I've editted the question , now its more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your updated samples in your post, you can use this regex,

```
B(\d{8})
```

which captures only eight digits preceded by `B` character.

```js
var match = /B(\d{8})/.exec("B012345678");
if (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
} else {
    console.log("Doesn't match")
}
```

Comment: can you explain ?

Comment: with input like B0123456789 it would not work, i need the output to be 01234567

Comment: Yes it will capture `0123456789`

Comment: @DorLugasi: Update your question and provide a better description of the input string you can get. Provide multiple different example that solutions can be verified against. Make sure to include the cases that make this problem difficult.

Comment: @DorLugasi: Do you want to capture all digits following `B` character or exactly 8 digits? From your new edited sample, it looks like you want only 8 digits. What should happen if it has less than 8 digits? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, only 8, that's why I've added the {8} in the regex expression i used

Comment: Great, Exactly what i was looking for, I'm sorry for all the misunderstanding before

Comment: @DorLugasi: Adding valid/invalid sample is a great way to clear confusions :)

Comment: will try better next question

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```js
let str = "B01234567TXXX";

let reg = /(?<=B)\d{8}/g

console.log(str.match(reg));
console.log("B012345670020".match(reg));
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ze9BRN/2)

Comment: can you explain the regex expression?

Comment: You mentioned B is always B and T is a character. Than how come you accept this to pass?

Comment: i meant character as in ASCII character ,I've editted the question , now its more clear

Comment: @DorLugasi you made it complicated with lack of explanation.No problem will help you mate :)

Comment: @DorLugasi bit more explanation will help if you tell what if the numbers are not exactly 8 or any other edge case, your expected output ?

Comment: This is a part of a barcode reader function, if the letters are in the formation mentioned so its an ID, else its a barcode, so anyway should be an output, meaning it could be B012345670020 but the output should still be 01234567

Comment: @DorLugasi You can check now. if you like you can upvote and select answer.

Comment: works great, but what is the(?<=B) part?
Eventually, I used Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi answer, but thank you for your time and I'm so sorry for the misunderstandings before

Comment: (?<=a)b (positive lookbehind) matches the b (and only the b) in cab, but does not match bed or debt. You can read here for info https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i voted up your answer

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that lookbehind assertions are a recent addition to the language and is not supported by all browsers yet.