# how save a console log into variable (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, console

Hi I'm trying to build a bot for a website,
This website prints a log on the console. I need to save it in a variable, but I only need the number inside the log. How do I do that?
I brought the sample log below

`Setting mine delay 1221299`

Comment: Not sure if i understand the question. If the website prints the log, can you just save it in a variable as string and then write the code to extract the numbers of the variable like here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607419/return-only-numbers-from-string/30607466

Comment: Maybe this answers your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript

Comment: I suppose you have access to the code that prints the output. 
Simply store the message into a variable before you pass to the log function `const msg = "Hello folks"; console.log(msg);`

Comment: console.log("data") .... const sample = "data"
instead of wrapping your code with console.log just put it in a variable .......