# JavaScript get number with comma from string

Tags: javascript

For example we have next string in javaScript

```
var str = "abc,de 55,5gggggg,hhhhhh 666 "
```

How i can get 55,5 as number?

Comment: Define the format of you numbers.

Comment: This can be done using regex and the match method. On mobile now so can't give you specifics but it should point you in the right direction. Possible regex: /([0-9,]+)/

Comment: Can you please explain your case a little bit more?
What should return in the case of "55,5 abc 44,5"?
I would advise looking into regular expressions and capture groups after you've refined your requirements http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to extract decimal number from string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411833/how-to-extract-decimal-number-from-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you can assume about your number, but for the example and a lot of cases this should work:

```js
var str = "abc,de 55,5gggggg,hhhhhh";
var match = /\d+(,\d+)?/.exec(str);
var number;
if (match) {
  number = Number(match[0].replace(',', '.'));
  console.log(number);
} else console.log("didnt find anything.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "abc,de 55,5gggggg,hhhhhh"

var intRegex = /\d+((.|,)\d+)?/
var number = str.match(intRegex);
console.log(number[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jiteshsojitra/5vk1mxxw/

```
var str = "abc,de 55,5gggggg,hhhhhh"
str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z ])/g, "").replace(/,\s*$/, "");
if (str.match(/,/g).length > 1) // if there's more than one comma
    str = str.replace(',', '');
alert (str);
```